# Is the future cost of carry a upper bound for the future price?

Tags: futures

The Future cost of carry model models the future price of a commodity.

$F = Se^{((r + s - c)t)}$

Where

$F$ = the future price of the commodity

$S$ = the spot price of the commodity

$r$ = the risk-free interest rate

$s$ = the storage cost expressed as a percentage of the spot price

$c$ = the convenience yield

$t$ = time to delivery of the contract expressed as a fraction of one year

This equation sounds weird to me. For example, consider an agricultural product that you can't reasonably store for over 2 years. Then the model seems to predict the future price of that agricultural product 2 years later to be infinity. This is of course absurd.

Are there better interpretation of the formula?

Comment: This equation is intended for **storable** commodities. (Such as many financial futures, precious metals, etc.). For agricultural I would not use it, except maybe for very short term. Also, for storable commodity, when the spot good cannot be shorted this equation is replaced by an inequality (upper bound). And this is the case for many physical commodities. But books like Hull are mainly discussing storable financial futures, like stock index; so they don't go into this (maybe just  footnote).